# Change email associated with git rep - to allow for heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I set up a rails app on a laptop, and started local git repository on that lap top.

I've copied that app folder onto another machine - using copy & paste.

From the second machine, I'm trying to deploy the app to Heroku.

I'm getting the following error -

```
 !  my.personal.email@gmail.com not authorized to access little-extras
```

I'd like to change the repo to be associated with the email I use for on my second laptop. As this is the email I have connected to my heroku account.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ssh key is associated with a different account than you created the application with.  One way to deal with this is to share the app with the account that the ssh key is associated with:

```
heroku sharing:add my.personal.email@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you probably need to run `heroku auth:login`.

Comment: thanks but it didn't work -  !   Fingerprint already exists. Please use one ssh key per Heroku account

Comment: I'm guessing that you have multiple Heroku accounts, and that the SSH key you're trying to upload is already associated with a different account. Have a read of: http://22ideastreet.com/debug/fingerprint-already-exists-please-use-one-ssh-key-per-heroku-account